# custom components - how to clone html template defined as js string literal?

Tags: javascript, templates, web-component, custom-component

I'm trying to understand how the different parts of vanilla web components work together.  I have defined a simple custom component and am trying to include a template.  I'm doing this since many browser vendors are not supporting html imports and moving towards using es6 modules instead.  Here's my web component:

```
var tmpl = `<template>
<h1>header</h1>
<p>copy</p>
</template>`;

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        let z = tmpl.cloneNode(true);
        this.appendChild(z);
    }
}

customElements.define('my-comopnent', MyComponent);
```

The error I get is Uncaught Type Error: cloneNode is not a function
I imagine that has something to do with the way I am defining my template as a string.

My question is this: how do I stamp out my template in a custom component where the template is defined as a javascript string literal?  Can I do so without additional dependencies or npm libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode `cloneNode` is a method that is on the `Node` interface.

In your code `tmpl` is not a `Node` but a `string`.

You need to do something like this at the top of your code:

```
let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
tmpl.innerHTML = `
<h1>header</h1>
<p>copy</p>
`;
```

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker, edit is ok - (1) `template` was not in the innerHTML..? (2) I was going to  update the string to be a string literal but you beat me to it

Comment: Yeah as far as what the innerHTML should be, I assumed the OP doesn’t want have `<template><template>…</template></template>`

Comment: Anyway, I think the more typical way to do would be to use `attachShadow` in the `MyComponent` constructor, like this:  'const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}); shadowRoot.innerHTML =
\`<h1>header</h1>
<p>copy</p>\`'. (Though you need to imagine the line breaks in that markup, because Stack Overflow eats them in comments.)

Comment: thanks @sideshowbarker.  i am aware of the typical way of setting innerhtml in a shadow root.  what im trying to figure out is how to use a template that isn't attached to the parent document so i can keep my component self contained.  Maybe I should make a new question...

Comment: @tim yeah a new question with that more-specific description would be good I think. But as far as the question you actually asked here, I think @itodd’s answer is a good response that will help others here at Stack Overflow who come across your question here in the future

Comment: @itodd is it necessary to have an actual document to attach to, or is this just using a static method of the document prototype?  Anyway, here's a better question for what I'm trying to do - thanks for your help!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097077/how-to-stamp-out-template-in-self-contained-custom-elements-with-vanilla-js